# Rails : has secure password stop me from registering new users in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following the Michael Hartl tutorial, and I don't understand why when I add the lines about password validation, I get:

```
created_at: nil 
updated_at: nil
```

It seems that there is a bug, and the user that I'm trying to create doesn't appear in my database...

Comment: `created_at` and `updated_at` get set automatically by active_record, you don't have to worry about those.  Are there validation errors?  When you do `user.valid?` and then `Rails.logger.debug(user.errors.full_messages.join("\n"))` what does your log output?  Do you have an example model? Where are you trying to save the user instance?  We need a little more information to help you.

Comment: First, I do rails console from my rails app directory. Then, I try this :  User.create(name:"John",email:"Doe@foo.bar",password:"lol").valid? 
and it says => False.

Comment: do this:  `user = User.create(...)` followed by `user.errors.full_messages` and see what the validation errors are.

Comment: Alright, well if my password is too short, that seems to be the problem. On the other hand, when it has a correct size, the windows prompt command displays tons of lines, and the resulting class seems to be ... nil.  :(

Do I need to have both password AND password_confirmation attributes for the whole process to make sense ?

Comment: What do you mean it display tons of lines and the resulting class seems to be nil?  Can you edit your original answer with the exact commands you're entering and the exact output you're seeing from the console?